# Is there a way to format a zip code in pandas using leading 00s

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a DF with a column dedicated to zip codes. The zip codes are all messed up and  I want to clean the column so that all zip codes will be  in the proper 5 digit format.

```
df1 =

    ZIP CODE  
0    35481  
1    45481  
2    881 
3    4074
4    8831-1591
```

Id like them to be formatted like this:

```
    ZIP CODE  
0    35481  
1    45481  
2    08810 
3    04074
4    08831
```

I created a function so that you could load in any series and fix the zip code problem.

Here is what I wrote:

```
def fix_zip(series):
      return series.astype(str).str.replace('[^\w\s]', '').str.zfill(5)
```

It works for most of the zip codes except I cant get it to get the zip codes to start with '0's instead it puts the 0s on the end.

So for example Ill get 40740 instead of 04074

Thanks for looking!

Comment: `881` -> `08810` shouldn't this be `00881`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get first consecutive digits by `extract`:

```
def fix_zip(series):
      return series.astype(str).str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False).str.zfill(5)

df['new'] = fix_zip(df['ZIP CODE'])
print (df)
   ZIP CODE    new
0      35481  35481
1      45481  45481
2        881  00881
3       4074  04074
4  8831-1591  08831
```

Or with split like:

```
def fix_zip(series):
      return series.astype(str).str.split('-').str[0].str.zfill(5)
```

If need processing values with length different way, here add one `0` before and `0` after:

```
def fix_zip(series):
      s =  series.astype(str).str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False)
      return s.str.zfill(5).mask(s.str.len().eq(3), '0' + s + '0')

df['new'] = fix_zip(df['ZIP CODE'])
print (df)
    ZIP CODE    new
0      35481  35481
1      45481  45481
2        881  08810
3       4074  04074
4  8831-1591  08831
```

Comment: but the OP code should also put '0' to the first position, isn't it?

Comment: @BrownBear - Do you think `881` ?

Comment: His code give me `00881` and `04074` of course it has logical errors for the last value ` 8831-1591` but the answer was `I cant get it to get the zip codes to start with '0's instead it puts the 0s on the end. So for example Ill get 40740 instead of 04074`

Comment: @BrownBear - yes, I cannot simulate `get 40740 instead of 04074`. But reason should be if data like `4074-0909` - then get with OP solution `40740`

Comment: yah it was supposed to be 00881 but thanks for the other solution as well!